# Background intelligent transfer with IIS server

Tags: iis, iis-7, hyper-v, upload, bits

I need help with setting my IIS server for BITS upload. i want to upload and download files from the virtual directory i have assigned to one of my websites. but  i m not able to upload and download files using BITS. i m not getting basic setting. like i have enabled client upload from BITS IIS Extension. when i try to upload file it gives error as "TRANSIENT Error" and for download it shows "CONNECTING" status, nut it doesnt really download.

command used for upload is in code section as ...
 Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous -Priority High -TransferPolicy Unrestricted -TransferType Upload -Destination http://myweb.com/vdir  -Source C:\a.exe -Authentication Ntlm -Credential WIN-DM6K7AGFQ5K\Administrator

any help will be appriciated, thank you.

Comment: Does it give the error right away, or does it take some time?

Comment: now i have added authentication type as ntlm and giving windows credentials to it....so for upload it is not giving "TRANSIENT ERROR" now...bt job state remains "Connecting" n no upload or download happens.